# mariadb-server is obsoleted by mysql-community-server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

hi I have this issue:

> maria db-server-5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by MySQL-community-server-5.7.27-1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to install MariaDB onto a machine which already has MySQL 5.7 running on it?

Comment: i don't know about the server its new to me i am trying to install openproject in godaddy vps server through ssh when i configure it has show like this.

Comment: If you need something specific to MariaDB, then don't go with the old 5.5, but instead use 10.3 or 10.4.  Otherwise, be happy with MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Got this issue on Oracle Cloud, turns out MySQL comes preinstalled on that type of compute node so I had to remove it first. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen